Method of Steepest Descent (deform contours where there are 2 saddles)
Question: use the method of steepest descent to obtain the first two non-zero terms in the asymptotic approximation
$$\int_0^\infty \exp(ix(t^3/3+t))dt\sim i(1/x+2/x^3+...+a_n/x^n)$$
as $x\to\infty$ and find an expression for $a_n$.
Thoughts: I have done the following: let $\phi(t) = i(t+t^3/3) = (-q -p^2q+q^3/3) + i(p-pq^2+p^3/3) =: u(p,q)+v(p,q)$, where $u$ is the real part function and $v$ is the imaginary part. The 2 saddles are $(p,q)=(0,\pm1)$, and by setting $v$ to $0$, I get the constant $v$ curve:
$p = 0$ or $ q = \pm\sqrt{p^2/3+1}$
I think the descent contours for $u$ would be $ q = +\sqrt{p^2/3+1}$ and $p=0,q<0$, i.e., the negative imaginary axis, while the others being ascent. Since I need to integrate along the positive real axis, I deformed the contour to the one along the negative imaginary axis (joined by other 2 straight lines, integrals from which I think will vanish). I then get the answer $\sqrt{\pi/x} i\exp(2x/3)$, however, this doesn't match the required result. Moreover, if I expand the exponential in my answer, I would get a series of positive $x$ powers, but the right answer should contain negative ones. I've checked my answers several times but couldn't figure out where I've gone wrong. I'd appreciate it if someone could help me out!

The integral in question can be expressed as
$$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - xf(t)} {\rm d}t} 
$$
where
$$
f(t) =  - {\rm i}\left( {\frac{{t^3 }}{3} + t} \right).
$$
The saddle points occur at $t =  \pm {\rm i}$. The condition $\operatorname{Re} f(t) > 0$ defines regions in the complex plane.  If we deform the integration contour within these regions, the integral's value remains unchanged (contributions from the arcs at infinity vanish). We would like to deform the contour of integration into one along which $\arg f(t)= 0$. You can verify that this can only be achived by passing through the saddle $\text{i}$. Consequently,
$$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - xf(t)} {\rm d}t}  = \int_0^{\rm i} {{\rm e}^{ - xf(t)} {\rm d}t}  + \int_{\rm i}^{+ \infty {\rm e}^{\pi {\rm i}/6} } {{\rm e}^{ - xf(t)} {\rm d}t} .\tag{1}
$$
In the first integral on the right-hand side (RHS), the contour is a vertical line connecting $0$ to $\mathrm{i}$. The second integral on the RHS involves a path of steepest descent originating from the saddle point at $\mathrm{i}$, extending towards infinity at an angle of $\pi/6$. Using the method of steepest descents, the second integral behaves as
$$
\int_{\rm i}^{+ \infty {\rm e}^{\pi {\rm i}/6} } {{\rm e}^{ - xf(t)} {\rm d}t}  \sim \frac{{\rm i}}{2}\sqrt {\frac{\pi }{x}} {\rm e}^{ - \frac{2}{3}x} 
$$
as $x\to+\infty$. This decay is exponentially faster than the anticipated algebraic decay. Therefore, the dominant contribution to the asymptotic expansion in negative powers of $x$ comes from the first integral on the RHS of $(1)$. By changing the integration variable from $t$ to $s$ using $t = \mathrm{i}s$, we find
$$
\int_0^{\rm i} {{\rm e}^{ - xf(t)} {\rm d}t}  = {\rm i}\int_0^1 {\exp \left( { - x\left( { - \frac{{s^3 }}{3} + s} \right)} \right){\rm d}s} .
$$
I will leave it to you as an exercise to complete the derivation of the asymptotic series.

thank you so much! I didn't integrate from 0 to i but simply computed the integral in the nbhd of the saddle. I believe this is where I've gone wrong. I've now done your exercise and found the correct answer. Thank you!
